# Setting a linear background of SVG using 256 RGB values

Tags: html, svg

I have a set of colour map that contains 256 RGB values (total of 256x3 = 768 values of RGB) that I want to set to a background of an SVG rectangle. Do I have to do:

```
 <stop offset="0.4%" stop-color="rgb(a,b,c)"/>
```

like 256 times? Or is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: here's an example that might come handy https://codepen.io/maio/pen/GZXWVq?editors=1010

Comment: That sounds more like something you should implement in canvas rather than SVG.

Comment: Also, it depends on what your RGB values are. For example, rgb(0 0 0) to rgb(255 0 0) would be doable. :)

Comment: @RobertLongson: Yes I have just given up on the idea of relying on SVG...

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: it is an entire colour map so we have several stops... I agree with few number of stops it is convenient to go that way.